# RAID degraded, partitions missing

Tags: ubuntu, raid

We're having a very weird issue at work. Our Ubuntu server has 6 drives, set up with RAID1 as follows:

```
/dev/md0, consisting of:
/dev/sda1
/dev/sdb1

/dev/md1, consisting of:
/dev/sda2
/dev/sdb2

/dev/md2, consisting of:
/dev/sda3
/dev/sdb3

/dev/md3, consisting of:
/dev/sdc1
/dev/sdd1

/dev/md4, consisting of:
/dev/sde1
/dev/sdf1
```

As you can see, md0, md1 and md2 all use the same 2 drives (split into 3 partitions). I also have to note that this is done via Ubuntu software raid, not hardware raid.

Today, the `/md0` RAID1 array shows as degraded - it is missing the `/dev/sdb1` drive. But since `/dev/sdb1` is only a partition (and `/dev/sdb2` and `/dev/sdb3` are working fine), it's obviously not the drive that's gone AWOL, it seems the partition itself is missing.

How is that even possible? And what could we do to fix it?

My output of cat `/proc/mdstat`:

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      24006528 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]


md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      1441268544 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]


md0 : active raid1 sda1[0]
      1464710976 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]


md3 : active raid1 sdd1[1] sdc1[0]
      2930133824 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]


md4 : active raid1 sdf2[1] sde2[0]
      2929939264 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]


unused devices: <none>
```

FYI: I tried the following:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1
```

But got this error:

```
mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/sdb1 as 2: Invalid argument
```

Comment: You probably got the 'invalid argument` since it is already part of the array and thus it is already added. This is why Rob's answer below does a remove first before re-adding it.

Answer (score 1):

First look at `/var/log/messages` (i.e. dmesg) to see why /dev/sdb1 was kicked off the RAID.  Chances are, there was an error reading or writing to /dev/sdb1.

If you run `smartctl -a /dev/sdb`, I suspect you'll find that the disk has a nonzero value for `reallocated sectors` or `current pending sectors`.  If it has a reallocated sector, the disk is starting to degrade and should be replaced immediately if this is a production server.  Although you can do `mdadm /dev/md0 -r /dev/sdb1` followed by `mdadm /dev/md0 -a /dev/sdb1` to remove and re-add the partition, you're better off backing up your data and replacing /dev/sdb right away.

To replace the disk, do the following:

1. Back up your data, and shut down the machine.
2. Record the serial number of each drive (so you know which one needs to be replaced).
3. Install your new hard disk, boot the machine, and verify the device names have not changed.  If device names have shifted, grab a piece of paper and note which new device name corresponds to each old name and serial number.  You may already already know this, but you can use `cat /proc/mdstat` to see which device names are in use by the RAIDs and `fdisk -l` or `smartctl -a <device>` to check the serial numbers.
4. Partition the new disk as appropriate (using the same partition sizes as on the other disks).
5. For each RAID, add the appropriate partition from the new drive with `mdadm <md device> -a <new disk partition>`  (Oh, and in case you were going to ask...yes, software RAID *is* that awesome.  You can add as many mirrors as you want to a Linux software RAID1.)
6. Periodically check the rebuild status with `cat /proc/mdstat`.
7. When the rebuild is complete, run `mdadm -f <md device> -f <bad disk's partition>` followed by `mdadm -f  -f  for each RAID1 that uses the bad disk.  This marks the bad disk's partition as failed, then removes it from the RAID.
8. Power down the machine and remove the bad disk.
9. If you want more than 1 mirror going forward, repeat steps 3-6 for one or more additional disks.  Otherwise, you'll have to use mdadm to resize the RAIDs back down to 2 devices (or else md will warn you about degraded arrays every time you reboot).

NOTE: if SMART diags do not report any critical errors for /dev/sdb, it may just be that /dev/sdb1 was kicked off /dev/md0 because it exceeded a timeout threshold.  In that case, /dev/sdb may be just fine but it wouldn't hurt to back up your data and add one or more additional mirrors anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First, back up that partition!

Then, first remove that drive from the array, then re-add it - however, check the dmesg first for the actual reason that it got removed...

Comment: But isn't that partition (sdb1)'s contents on sda1 as it is? Otherwise the system wouldn't run. Or am I misunderstanding you? :)

Comment: You are correct, the contents are on sda1 as well. But if you are going to work on a filesystem which is not acting as you expected it to then the safe method is to make a backup first. And if all goes well you will not need that backup.

Comment: @reano the danger in doing the rebuild without trying to perform a backup first is that the remaining disk could fail during the rebuild.  If you do the backup first, then you at least have the files you were able to read before the remaining disk failed. This is also why it's a good idea to add more levels of redundancy (additional mirrors in software RAID1, or e.g. going from RAID5 to RAID6).